# Required screen resolution not available Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: xorg, display, display-resolution

I've tried to set up a new screen resolution of 1920x1080 with 60Hz refresh rate,
I was following this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LiP-YqtZoNQ

I was able to add the mentioned resolution, but when I try to apply the change, I get the following error:

```
required virtual size does not fit available size: requested=(1920, 1080), minimum=(1024, 768), maximum=(1024, 768)
```

[Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M97Ln.png)

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

**UPDATE:**
I've added a graphics card to my motherboard and the problem solved

Comment: Are you using a VGA port?

Comment: No, I'm using my built in HDMI port on a Gigabyte Z370 HD3 Motherboard

Comment: I have had a similar problem, ubuntu 9.0.4, suddenly the system didn't recognized the monitor. I did *xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA "1920x1080_60.00"
xrandr --output VGA --mode "1920x1080_60.00"
xrandr: screen cannot be larger than 1360x1360 (desired size 1920x1080)* repeatedly, and tried to work the monitor panel. Then, suddenly, this panel proposed me the option to add this solution to the configuration.

Comment: Part 2: I did, and it worked since. I havn't dared to shutdown the system or disconnect the monitor, and really don't know what exactly happened.

Comment: Part 3: connecting the monitor with a different box showed the same symptoms. Wiering with HDMI worked perfectly, so in my case, it is a hardware fault on side of the monitor.